# How do I read an 85 FPS webcam on windows without incurring multiple frames of latency?

Tags: windows, usb, uvc

I am having trouble reading an ~85 FPS USB webcam Windows, on average I am measuring 85 Hz but its being read in bursts.

I have a python script like below to capture images

```
import cv2 as cv
import sys
from datetime import datetime

previous_time = datetime.now()

n = int(sys.argv[1])
cam = cv.VideoCapture(n)
while 1:
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    now = datetime.now()
    td = (now-previous_time).microseconds
    previous_time = now
    print("Frame delta, {} ms".format(td/1000))
```

When looking at the printed output, the time delta between frames is either 30 ms or near 0ms.

```
Frame delta, 30.877 ms
Frame delta, 0.0 ms
Frame delta, 0.999 ms
Frame delta, 30.525 ms
Frame delta, 0.0 ms
Frame delta, 0.997 ms
Frame delta, 29.956 ms
```

I have tested the same webcam on Linux with the same script and the frame delta is a lot more consistent (close to 12 ms with +- 5ms deviation) which is what I am expecting.
I have tried the Microsoft Media foundation backend with OpenCV and also the direct show backend, both have the same behavior. I have even tried write a C++ version of the script using the Microsoft Media Foundation API and it has the same issue.

Comment: Can you tell if it is actually dropping frames or merely being a bit erratic about delivering them to your computer? Windows was never very real time friendly. Filming a steadily rotating disk or mains powered fan should help determine if the varying frame delta is actually due to losing some frames.

Comment: It's not dropping frames, if I average over one second I do have 85 FPS which is the same as Linux. The USB descriptors say that the webcam is 85 FPS too.

Comment: Device driver level is probably buffering frames then and so  you get two frames almost instantly and one with a big delay. Windows at application isn't very real time friendly.

Comment: Yeah this is what I worry about because practically I can't do anything about this if this is an issue with USBVideo.sys . It does make you wonder how windows supports the Kinect and other devices where latency would be a concern.